# laravel-image-optimizer InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, laravel

при установке пакета

```
composer require spatie/laravel-image-optimizer
```

выскакивает

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Package spatie/laravel-image-optimizer at version  has a PHP requirement in
  compatible with your PHP version (5.6.38)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Package spatie/laravel-image-optimizer](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-image-optimizer) требует версии Laravel 5.7.

> This package is the Laravel 5.7

Соответственно, [Laravel 5.7 требует версии PHP не ниже 7.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation):

> PHP >= 7.1.3

Вы же пытаетесь скормить его несовместимому PHP:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>     Package spatie/laravel-image-optimizer at version  has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version (5.6.38)
>
> Пакет spatie/laravel-image-optimizer в версии имеет требование PHP, несовместимое с вашей версией PHP (5.6.38)

Нескладушки, однако! Вы или PHP до нужной версии догоните, или требование к нему понизьте сменой версии Laravel и spatie/laravel-image-optimizer. Судя по гитхабу, есть релиз spatie/laravel-image-optimizer v.1.0.1 для Laravel 5.4, а у того требование к PHP как раз  >= 5.6.4. Правда что там с функциональностью и какие отличия от последней версии - я не интересовался.

З.Ы. У Laravel есть такая себе виртуальная заранее подготовленная и сконфигурированная среда разработки и отладки - [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead). Настоятельно рекомендую установить. Разработка и отладка в Homestead позволяет выбирать и конфигурировать среду выполнения под нужную версию Лары. Очень удобно. Сейчас пишу под 5.5, черед час - под 5.8, и смена среды разработки занимает 5 минут, и переустанавливать ничего не надо.